# draw the sum value above the stacked bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

How do I draw the sum value of each class (in my case: a=450, b=150, c=290, d=90) above the stacked bar in ggplot2？ Here is my code：

```
#Data
hp=read.csv(textConnection(
"class,year,amount
a,99,100
a,100,200
a,101,150
b,100,50
b,101,100
c,102,70
c,102,80
c,103,90
c,104,50
d,102,90"))
hp$year=as.factor(hp$year)

#Plotting
p=ggplot(data=hp)  
p+geom_bar(binwidth=0.5,stat="identity")+  
aes(x=reorder(class,-value,sum),y=value,label=value,fill=year)+
theme()
```

Comment: You have a column `amount` in the data but `-value` in the aesthetics; shouldn't those be the same?

Comment: Indeed. I tried to edit to fix the example, but the edit was rejected...
The `aes` call should be: `aes(x=reorder(class,-amount,sum),y=amount,label=amount,fill=year)+`

Comment: [Very related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691580/can-i-use-geom-text-or-similar-to-add-group-by-sum-rather-than-amending-original/44691975#44691975)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this by creating a dataset of per-class totals (this can be done multiple ways but I prefer [dplyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html)):

```
library(dplyr)
totals <- hp %>%
    group_by(class) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(value))
```

Then adding a `geom_text` layer to your plot, using `totals` as the dataset:

```
p + geom_bar(binwidth = 0.5, stat="identity") +  
    aes(x = reorder(class, -value, sum), y = value, label = value, fill = year) +
    theme() +
    geom_text(aes(class, total, label = total, fill = NULL), data = totals)
```

You can make the text higher or lower than the top of the bars using the `vjust` argument, or just by adding some value to `total`:

```
p + geom_bar(binwidth = 0.5, stat = "identity") +  
    aes(x = reorder(class, -value, sum), y = value, label = value, fill = year) +
    theme() +
    geom_text(aes(class, total + 20, label = total, fill = NULL), data = totals)
```

[image]

Comment: how can we add value for each year in bars ?

Comment: @Mostafa please visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447548/add-data-labels-to-stacked-bar-chart-in-r).

Answer (score 43):

You can use the built-in summary functionality of `ggplot2` directly:

```
ggplot(hp, aes(reorder(class, -amount, sum), amount, fill = year)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = after_stat(y), group = class), 
    stat = 'summary', fun = sum, vjust = -1
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I needed to change 
     fun.y = sum
to
     fun.y = sum
for this to work.