# Can I use geom_text or similar to add group by sum rather than amending original data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a bar plot:

```
ggplot(filtered_funnel, aes(x = reorder(Funnel, -Sessions), y = Sessions)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#008080", alpha = 0.6) +
      xlab("Step") +
      ylab("Events") +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(l) {l = l / 1000; paste0(l, "K")}) +
      geom_text(aes(label = Sessions, group = Channel), color = "white")
```

It looks like this (note the text labels in white):
[image]

This is because the data df `filtered_funnel` is actually split out by a field "Channel". I need the bar to be based on the grouped sum of e.g. sessions rather than each individual channel sessions.

Here's a glimpse of the source data:

```
> glimpse(filtered_funnel)
Observations: 108
Variables: 4
$ Channel  <chr> "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", ...
$ Promo    <chr> "apples", "apples", "apples", "banannas", "banannas", "banannas", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "none", "none", "none...
$ Funnel   <chr> "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetai...
$ Sessions <dbl> 3993, 6332, 2224, 1237, 1962, 689, 2234, 3543, 1244, 42378, 4672, 28120, 87187, 7408, 2602, 611, 969, 340, 4462, 7280, 2...


filtered_funnel
Source: local data frame [108 x 4]
Groups: Channel, Promo [?]

   Channel    Promo          Funnel Sessions
     <chr>    <chr>           <chr>    <dbl>
1   Direct   apples        Checkout     3993
2   Direct   apples ShippingDetails     6332
3   Direct   apples    Transactions     2224
4   Direct banannas        Checkout     1237
5   Direct banannas ShippingDetails     1962
6   Direct banannas    Transactions      689
7   Direct  carrots        Checkout     2234
8   Direct  carrots ShippingDetails     3543
9   Direct  carrots    Transactions     1244
10  Direct     none       AddToCart    42378
# ... with 98 more rows
```

It looks like ggplot is adding the individual values of each component rather than the sum e.g. just for the first bar in the image (Sessions step)

```
> filtered_funnel %>% filter(Funnel == "Sessions")
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: Channel, Promo [6]

   Channel Promo   Funnel Sessions
     <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
1   Direct  none Sessions    87187
2    Email  none Sessions   110035
3 Facebook  none Sessions    79734
4  Organic  none Sessions    80768
5      SEM  none Sessions    94610
6  Youtube  none Sessions    66681
```

I can see the value 110035 on the image and in the table. What I actually want ggplot to do is add the sum total for sessions.

Since this is being done within a Shiny app I'm trying to avoid medling with the source data since I'm using filter box inputs to filter the data frame. Also, I saw other SO answers that seemed to suggest what I wnat is possible, I just couldn't get it to work e.g.

- [draw the sum value above the stacked bar in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656846/draw-the-sum-value-above-the-stacked-bar-in-ggplot2)

How can I get ggplot to add the sum total for each bar? Can I do this using ggplot grouping and summing rather than altering the source data I feed into ggplot in the aes?

---- dput of data---
Following a comment, here's the data (which has been randomly generated anyway so no NDA issues)

```
> dput(filtered_funnel)
structure(list(Channel = c("Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", 
"Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", 
"Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", 
"Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", 
"Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", 
"Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", 
"Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", 
"Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", 
"Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Organic", "Organic", "Organic", 
"Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "Organic", 
"Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "Organic", 
"Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", 
"SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", 
"SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", 
"Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", 
"Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", 
"Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube"), Promo = c("apples", "apples", 
"apples", "banannas", "banannas", "banannas", "carrots", "carrots", 
"carrots", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "pears", 
"pears", "pears", "apples", "apples", "apples", "banannas", "banannas", 
"banannas", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "none", "none", 
"none", "none", "none", "none", "pears", "pears", "pears", "apples", 
"apples", "apples", "banannas", "banannas", "banannas", "carrots", 
"carrots", "carrots", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", 
"none", "pears", "pears", "pears", "apples", "apples", "apples", 
"banannas", "banannas", "banannas", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", 
"none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", "pears", "pears", 
"pears", "apples", "apples", "apples", "banannas", "banannas", 
"banannas", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "none", "none", 
"none", "none", "none", "none", "pears", "pears", "pears", "apples", 
"apples", "apples", "banannas", "banannas", "banannas", "carrots", 
"carrots", "carrots", "none", "none", "none", "none", "none", 
"none", "pears", "pears", "pears"), Funnel = c("Checkout", "ShippingDetails", 
"Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "AddToCart", "Checkout", 
"Registrations", "Sessions", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", 
"Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "AddToCart", "Checkout", 
"Registrations", "Sessions", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", 
"Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "AddToCart", "Checkout", 
"Registrations", "Sessions", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", 
"Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "AddToCart", "Checkout", 
"Registrations", "Sessions", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", 
"Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "AddToCart", "Checkout", 
"Registrations", "Sessions", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", 
"Transactions", "Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", "AddToCart", "Checkout", 
"Registrations", "Sessions", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions", 
"Checkout", "ShippingDetails", "Transactions"), Sessions = c(3993, 
6332, 2224, 1237, 1962, 689, 2234, 3543, 1244, 42378, 4672, 28120, 
87187, 7408, 2602, 611, 969, 340, 4462, 7280, 2304, 549, 896, 
283, 2094, 3417, 1081, 42251, 5666, 29094, 110035, 9244, 2926, 
256, 418, 132, 129, 191, 85, 3078, 4557, 2039, 120, 178, 79, 
13977, 90, 9727, 79734, 134, 59, 1142, 1691, 756, 3125, 4655, 
1985, 1724, 2568, 1095, 3109, 4631, 1975, 34756, 2864, 23453, 
80768, 4266, 1819, 249, 371, 158, 1839, 2661, 1223, 1543, 2232, 
1026, 2007, 2904, 1335, 24090, 1792, 15272, 94610, 2593, 1192, 
479, 693, 318, 800, 1245, 522, 1734, 2698, 1132, 930, 1447, 607, 
22349, 1436, 14478, 66681, 2235, 937, 1579, 2457, 1031)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -108L), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("Channel", "Promo", 
"Funnel", "Sessions"), indices = list(0:2, 3:5, 6:8, 9:14, 15:17, 
    18:20, 21:23, 24:26, 27:32, 33:35, 36:38, 39:41, 42:44, 45:50, 
    51:53, 54:56, 57:59, 60:62, 63:68, 69:71, 72:74, 75:77, 78:80, 
    81:86, 87:89, 90:92, 93:95, 96:98, 99:104, 105:107), group_sizes = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L), biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
    Channel = c("Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", "Direct", 
    "Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", "Email", "Facebook", 
    "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Organic", 
    "Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "Organic", "SEM", "SEM", 
    "SEM", "SEM", "SEM", "Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", "Youtube", 
    "Youtube"), Promo = c("apples", "banannas", "carrots", "none", 
    "pears", "apples", "banannas", "carrots", "none", "pears", 
    "apples", "banannas", "carrots", "none", "pears", "apples", 
    "banannas", "carrots", "none", "pears", "apples", "banannas", 
    "carrots", "none", "pears", "apples", "banannas", "carrots", 
    "none", "pears")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("Channel", 
"Promo")))
```

Comment: Use `dput(filtered_funnel)` to share your data

Comment: Hi added this now, any help appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `stat_summary` to calculate the sums, and use that for both the y position and the label:

```
ggplot(filtered_funnel, aes(x = reorder(Funnel, -Sessions), y = Sessions)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "#008080", alpha = 0.6) +
  stat_summary(
    aes(label = stat(y)), fun.y = 'sum', geom = 'text', col = 'white', vjust = 1.5
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(l) {l = l / 1000; paste0(l, "K")})  +
  xlab("Step") + ylab("Events")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much (again)! This is great. May I ask some follow ups?
What is ..y.. ? Why did you choose (how did you know to choose) `stat_summary()` over `geom_text()`?

Comment: `..y..` is the calculated statistic. Each stat (except `identity`) calculates some values before plotting, and you can access those values by their names surrounded with `..`. You can define layers by their `stats` or `geoms`, it usually doesn't matter, you could use `geom_text(aes(label = ..y..), fun.y = 'sum', stat = 'summary', col = 'white', vjust = 1.5)` as well.

Comment: Thanks this really helps. "..y.. is the calculated statistic". The calculated statistics of what? `fun.y = "sum"`? What else could I have added to label (even something nonsensical) just so that it really clicks? (Hope you don't mind the follow ups, I just really value your help here while I have the opportunity)

Comment: `stat_summary` summarizes `y` for each `x`. So it calculates a new `y`. You can access this new `y` with `..y..`. If you use `..x..` you get numbers 1 to 6. For other stats you get access to other calculated values. For example, if you look at the [docs page](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html) for `stat_bin` there is a section "Computed variables" with several options, such as `ndensity`. You can access this variable with `..ndensity..` when using `stat_bin` as your `stat` (either directly or in a `geom`).

Comment: "stat_summary summarizes y for each x". Clicked. Thanks a lot!