# Add Data Labels to Stacked Bar Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe looks like this:

```
team  played  wins  draws  losses  scored  conceded
 A       5      3     1       1       12       4
 B       7      3     3       1       16       8      
 C       3      0     1       2       2        14
 D       5      2     2       1       12       7
```

I managed to create a stacked bar with wins, draws, losses with ggplot:
[image]

Using the following code:

```
df %>% select(team,wins,draws,losses) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -team) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("wins", "draws", "losses"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = team, y=value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) + coord_flip()
```

Now, I was trying to add data labels. I tried using `+ geom_text(label = name)` but that doesn't work. I'd like the final result to look as follows:
[image]

If it's possible to add total data labels (i.e. sum of wins, draws, losses) as seen on the right of each column, that'd be great.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

As a staring point

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <-  read.table(text="team  played  wins  draws  losses  scored  conceded
A       5      3     1       1       12       4
B       7      3     3       1       16       8      
C       3      0     1       2       2        14
D       5      2     2       1       12       7", header=T)


totals <- df_example %>%
  select(team,wins,draws,losses) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -team) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("wins", "draws", "losses"))) %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(value))  


df_example %>%
  select(team,wins,draws,losses) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -team) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("wins", "draws", "losses"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = team, y=value, fill = name,label = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = value,family = "serif"), position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE,vjust = 0.5))+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "serif", color = "black", size = 15))+ 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(family = "serif", color = "black", size = 12))+
  geom_text(aes(team, total + 0.1, label = total, fill = NULL,family = "serif"), data = totals)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Since I cannot add a new answer, I have edited your answer.

Comment: @BappaDas Ok no problem